# new column that repeats number for specific rows R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame and I want to add a new column that repeats 1 for specific rows.

```
b <- data.frame(var1 = c(9.2, 3.5,5.5,8,3), var2 = 1:5,row.names = c("a","b","c","d","e"))
b$new_col <- rep("1",b[1:3,])

Error in rep("1", b[1:3, ]) : invalid 'times' argument
```

I want b to look like this

```
 var1 var2 new_col
a  9.2    1       1
b  3.5    2       1
c  5.5    3       1
d  8.0    4       0
e  3.0    5       0
```

How can I do that?

EDIT: In my real problem. I want to add several columns with 1 in specific rows. Like that

```
 var1 var2 new_col new_col2
a  9.2    1       1        0
b  3.5    2       1        0
c  5.5    3       1        0
d  8.0    4       0        1
e  3.0    5       0        1
f  2.0    6       0        0
g  3.0    7       0        0
h  5.0    8       0        0
```

Comment: What is the condition for adding 1?

Comment: I want to label specific rows. The new column is the label and the rows should be in this group or label. Which rows are in which label is a manmade decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `%in%` to compare row from `seq_len(nrow(b)` to *give a `1` in specific rows.*

```
b$new_col <- +(seq_len(nrow(b)) %in% 1:3)
b$new_col2 <- +(seq_len(nrow(b)) %in% 4:5)
#b
#  var1 var2 new_col new_col2
#a  9.2    1       1        0
#b  3.5    2       1        0
#c  5.5    3       1        0
#d  8.0    4       0        1
#e  3.0    5       0        1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
b$new_col <- as.numeric(1:nrow(b) < 4)

  var1 var2 new_col
a  9.2    1       1
b  3.5    2       1
c  5.5    3       1
d  8.0    4       0
e  3.0    5       0
```

Answer (score 0):

For transparency I'd probably add an explicit row number column and use that to select the rows. e.g.:

```
b <- data.frame(var1 = c(9.2, 3.5,5.5,8,3), var2 = 1:5,row.names = c("a","b","c","d","e"))
b$row_num <- 1:nrow(b)

rows_to_choose <- 1:3
b$new_col <- ifelse(b$row_num %in% rows_to_choose, 1, 0)
```

```
  var1 var2 row_num new_col
a  9.2    1       1       1
b  3.5    2       2       1
c  5.5    3       3       1
d  8.0    4       4       0
e  3.0    5       5       0
```